# Google Analytics - Can I create VISITOR based dynamic segments in the API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

This is an EXPERT Google analytics question (you've been warned).

In the GA user interface I can create a segment based on a USER and not a VISIT.

When using the dynamic segments in the API I've discovered the segment is VISIT based.
Is is *possible* to tell the API I want to create a dynamic segment based on USER instead (like in the GUI)?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this some more and found that as of Dec 13, 2013 it is NOT possible to create dynamic user based segments via the API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you even cant retrieve Id of Segment with visitor filtration, even if exists in Web interface.